# How do I create an ethereum burn address?

Tags: ethereum

I would like to create an Ethereum address `0x.....` without a private key. Obviously one way to do it is to generate one from a paper wallet and throw away the key.

But is there another way to create one without a key? (I am not certain if the Ethereum blockchain checks an address for validity outside of the `0x` prefix)

Comment: Here is more information: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-address-and-private-key-from-a-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid Ethereum address is a checksum hex representation of a 20byte number starting with a `0x`.

So anything between `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and `0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF` is a valid Ethereum address.

---

You can generate a random 20byte number with openssl or a similar tool:

```
openssl rand -hex 20
```

*Example output: `b69c34f580d74396daeb327d35b4fb4677353fa9`*

And then checksum it:

> *This case-sensivity is used for checksum validation. The address is compared against the raw binary keccak-256 hash of the address bytes, and where there are letters in the same corresponding place as a “1” bit, the letter is capitalized.*

Source: https://coincodex.com/article/2078/ethereum-address-checksum-explained/

Easier than calculating the hash and adjusting the letter capitalization based on that hash, is using a library that generates the checksum address (from a non-checkum address) for you - for example [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#tochecksumaddress)

*Example output: `0xB69c34f580d74396Daeb327D35B4fb4677353Fa9`*

And you have a [valid address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xB69c34f580d74396Daeb327D35B4fb4677353Fa9) without ever knowing the private key.