# Remix not recognizing WMATIC address in an array

Tags: solidity

I am stuck trying to compile a contract using Remix. I am initializing an array as follows:

```
address[] public wmaticToUsdcPath =[0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270, 0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174];
```

But Remix won't compile and is complaining that 0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270 is not an error. The exact error is, this looks like an array but has an invalid checksum. It is suggesting I prepend '00' to it and directing me to https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#address-literals but I can't seem to understand what to do. Prepending '00' will change the address. I am working on the MATIC/Polygon network.

The funny thing is if I declare an address variable and assign the WMATIC address to it, it is accepted by the compiler.

Does anyone know why the MATIC address is not accepted in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I just need to follow the instruction in the error message. I prefix the address with '00' and it solved the issue. The issue was caused because WMATIC (and also USDC) have address format that will not pass checksum for later versions of solidity. By adding the '00' it will make it pass the checksum during compilation but the address will still be the same on deploying (I was worried adding this will change the address of the token). My final solution looked like this:

```
address[] public wmaticToUsdcPath =[address(0x000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270), address(0x002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to checksum the addresses.

Checksum of an address is basically adjusting capitalization of the letters (hex values a-f) based on values of the address hash. There are some tools to calculate the address checksum, for example [this one](https://ethsum.netlify.app/). You can see the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66592520/1693192) for more detailed explanation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address[] public wmaticToUsdcPath = [
        0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270,  // instead of 0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270
        0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174   // mind the capitalization of the letters
    ];
}
```